# Import custom registered block to another custom block in Gutenberg

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I've created a custom Button block and want to use it inside other blocks, like CTA or Icon feature.
I've saw in some plugins such code, that exports registered block:

`export default registerBlockType( 'name_space/button', {`

But now i want to import it to another block for future use. Something like that:

`import CustomButton from '../custom-button/block';`

I've tried include it inside `edit` method of another block with `{CustomButton}` and `<CustomButton />` . But every time i get an error.

I there a way to do such thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [InnerBlocks](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/tree/master/packages/block-editor/src/components/inner-blocks) for using core or custom blocks in your blocks. Please keep in mind that it can only be used once inside a block.

Comment: Yeap, i've solve it in the same way. But unfortunately it has some limitations.thanks.

Comment: Glad to know that, yes it have some limitations but I think we can solve most of them by following's Matt advice (founder of WordPress) "Thinks Blocks Deeply".

Comment: Innerblocks are just not at a point where you can see dynamic changes from the parent block. When I attempt to pass "props" from the parent to the children, the children don't update. At least, not in the editor.

Comment: @trevdev It is good to make child blocks independent from parent blocks for our own convenience so in this way there will be no props to pass. We just pass props on initialization via attributes on InnerBlocks.

If you have a need to change values of child blocks then data api of Gutenberg can help you with that but I will prefer to first try to make it independent.

Comment: This is where gutenberg and react diverge I guess. I'll look up the data api and see if I can accomplish what I need using that, but honestly, it would be nice to have more Reactivity and less sandboxing. It really chaffs the freedom that I have developing with reactive frameworks.

Comment: You are still developing with reactive frameworks and it's a lot better then what WordPress used to have (shortcodes). It's a bit different because it's the block approach of doing things.